# What are these connector threaded standoffs called?

Tags: identification, connector, hardware

These threaded standoffs are used on DB connectors and seem to be flared onto the connector flange. They are used to secure two mating connectors together.

What are they called? What kind of tool is used to install them onto the connector?

[image: DB connector standoff]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic search word you're looking for is "swage", from the associated metalworking process, "[swaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaging)".  (The product is called a "swage spacer".)

The usual manufacturers of standoff hardware will make them, along with the required swaging die (used with a hammer or arbor press) to attach the spacer to the PCB or connector.

1. [Example spacer](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/215/4882-1001826.pdf)
2. [Example die](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/215/309-742627.pdf)

The die may also be called a "staking tool".

Answer (score 2):

There are D shell connectors with the stand-offs as part of the connector itself.
You can have board side, mating side or both, either M3 or 4-40.
Here is an example of a board [side connector](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/conec/164A16579X/1017289).

Comment: Yes, but stock is low right now and we could only get connectors w/o the standoffs.